# Get format of Date for date column in Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache, date, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI 3.11 version for reading and writing an excel file in Java

In my input excel file, I have a column which contains date. Date can be in any format like say dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm or yy/mm/dd  etc. While reading the file, I can get date in any format.

[image]

When I am creating the new excel file as output, I want to write date column. But I want to use the same format of date that was present in the input excel file.

Is there any way, by which I can get out the date format present in the input excel file (Above screen shot you can see the date was in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss PM format)

I do not want to use `***getCellStyle***` function, because it returns me the complete style of cell including the font color, background color etc.
I just want the date format information of a cell that was present in the input excel file.

Way I am trying :

```
CellStyle outputStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
Font textFont = wb.createFont();
 textFont.setFontName("Arial");
textFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
textFont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
.setFont(textFont);

 if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(icell)) {
 outputStyle.setDataFormat(icell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat());
 ocell.setCellValue(icell.getDateCellValue());
 }

 ocell.setCellStyle(outputStyle);
```

It is writing the value of Date in the cell as number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the whole [`CellStyle`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html) object returned by `getCellStyle`, only the *data format string* of the cell style returned by [`getDataFormatString`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#getDataFormatString%28%29) with the help of [`CreationHelper`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CreationHelper.html):

```
// Create the cell style in the new WorkBook
CreationHelper createHelper = outputWB.getCreationHelper();
CellStyle outputStyle = outputWB.createCellStyle(); 

// Set the data format using the data format string
outputStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat()
        .getFormat(cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString()));
// Set the created cell style to the new cell
newCell.setCellStyle(outputStyle);
```

Variable `cell` is the `Cell` read from the current file and variable `newCell` is the `Cell` to be written into the new file.

Comment: Are you writing the value as `Date`? Could you include in your question at least how you write and how you write the date cells?

Comment: Yes I am writing as a Date type of value.. CellStyle outputStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
Font textFont = wb.createFont();
 textFont.setFontName("Arial");
textFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
textFont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
.setFont(textFont);
     
 if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(icell)) {
 outputStyle.setDataFormat(icell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat());
 ocell.setCellValue(icell.getDateCellValue());
 }
 
 ocell.setCellStyle(outputStyle);

Comment: Updated the code in question. Please have a look.. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: I've updated the answer for you. I hope this second approach works also for you.

Comment: Thanks you so much for quick response. Second approach worked for me. I want to achieve the same thing using JXL api also. As for excel sheet with xls extension, I am using jxl library. Any help on this?

Comment: Apache POI also supports xls format. Why don't you use that? The code-base can be the same, you just have to write to HSSFWorkbook rather than XSSFWorkbook.

Comment: Code is legacy and huge. So cannot switch to Apache POI for xls format.